# What's the point of slow mode/half speed?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

There is a button that enables slow mode where your characters only move half as fast.

[image]

What exactly is the point of this mode? Scouting is a separate mode with clear benefits, but I don't really see the point of moving at half speed. Are there any benefits to this mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not just that your characters move half as fast, it's that the entire game moves half as fast. This way you can play without pausing and still have enough time to plan out your moves.

There is also a double speed option (D by default) which makes the game moves at, well, double speed.

Comment: Double Speed + Scouting Mode is the best thing.

Comment: I completely missed that it slows down everything, I first triggered it accidentally with the keyboard shortcut and without context it looked like just slow walking.

Answer (score 3):

It's primarily useful in combat, when things can get very hectic. Running a large scale battle with a lot of targets running around can get annoying - *especially* if you're pausing *every time* you want to issue an order or change targets. Running in slow motion gives you more time to react and pay attention to what's happening without pausing constantly.

It can also be used when in Scouting Mode to more precisely judge the exact edges of the range at which enemies will notice you.